# Mysql : Fetching the data except negative values

Tags: mysql

I am fetching the data from table(XXX) while fetching i want to discard the rows containing negative values in the column(YYY). Please help me out in writing mysql query for the above condition. Thankyou

Comment: Atleast provide field name..

Comment: put table structure and which column has negative values?

Comment: What have YOU tried so far.?? And please don't ask homework questions here.

Comment: Veer i tried select * from XXX where YYY!=like '-%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM XXX
WHERE YYY>=0
```